# npm warn deprecated circular-json@0.5.9 while install angular 7

Tags: angular-cli, angular-cli-v7

I'm installing angular 7 but its giving error, when i create new project.

node -v
v10.12.0

npm -v
6.4.1

Error Screenshot

[image]

This is another issue:-

'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the following command before you create the new app using angular CLI:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

It will clean the cache forcefully.

Comment: now it working fine thanks! but i'm getting another error 'git' is not recognized screenprint updated in question.

Comment: Then you need to install git in your system, have you installed git? If not, look [here](https://git-scm.com/download/win).